# Display database on DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, displayobject

It shows "asdfghjk sdfgh", so why am I unable to remove it.

[image: img]

Comment: Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the question not as a picture behind a link.

Answer (score 0):

In your Properties of your DataGridView, set you AllowEdit/Add/Delete property to true, you will then be able to add edit or delete any rows that you want, you can also disable these later if you dont want to allow any form of editing on your DataGridView

Comment: if this has worked for you please remember to mark as answer